# @Transactional annotations in junit - spring and jms

Tags: java, spring, junit, jms

Here is my test method:

```
public TestClass extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @Test
   public myTest() {

       this.userService.doStuff();

       Thread.sleep(ENOUGH_TIME_FOR_JMS_MESSAGES_TO_BE_CONSUMED);

       assert(stuff happend by consumers);

   }
```

the UserService:

```
@Service
public UserService {

   @Transactional
   public void doStuff() {
     entity.getLazyField().doSomething();
     jmsTemplate.produce(SOME_MESSAGE_FOR_MANY_CONSUMERS);
   }
}
```

On of the consumers that listens to the produced event:

```
public SomeConsumer{

   @Transactional
   public void onMessage(Message someMessage) {
     saveSomeEntity();
     updateSomeOtherStuffOnDB();
   }
}
```

So, Problem is when i run the test above, i get a lazy initialize exception.
For some reason I'm not whitihn a transaction on the test even though there is a @Transactional annotation.

So i tried to change the test signature to:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public myTest() {..}
```

This way the lazy error is gone, but the events of the jms are only fired when the WHOLE test is completed!

I can't seem to make them both work at once.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is without seeing correct code. Where does `entity` come from? What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: entity being fetched by a simple spring-data repository (find method). I forgot to add that on the production the whole thing executes perfectly. meaning its a problem that resides on the junit

Comment: That doesn't tell me where the entity comes from. When is it fetched from the repository? By which component? Inside or outside the transaction. That's what matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed the problem, it had nothing to do with all the above , it was due to a mockup i created. Pretty weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Check your transaction configuration in your test's context file. You can also up the logging level in your log4j to `DEBUG` for `org.springframework` to see when transactions start and end.